# MongoClient doesn't read from secondary server

Tags: java, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to use a cluster of documentDB on AWS.
On this cluster, I have 2 instances, one primary for writeOps and one secondary for readOps...

If I create the connection with connectionString like this:

```java
String host = getHost();
Integer port = Integer.parseInt(getPort());
String[] arrCredentials = getCredentials();
String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", arrCredentials[0], arrCredentials[1]);
String database = getDatabase();
String options = "ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred";
    
String connection = String.format("mongodb://%s@%s:%d/%s?%s", 
                        credentials, host, port, database, options);
return MongoClients.create(new ConnectionString(connection));
```

It works well, and the readOps are served by the secondary instance...

But, when I try to use `MongoClients.create()` this way:

```java
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(settings ->
                    settings
                         .hosts(singletonList(new ServerAddress(
                                    getHost(), Integer.parseInt(getPort()))))
                         .requiredReplicaSetName("rs0")
                         .requiredClusterType(ClusterType.REPLICA_SET)
            )
            .applyToSslSettings(setting ->
                    setting.enabled(true)
            )
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
            .credential(getCredential())
            .build());
}
```

All calls, readOps and writeOps, are served by the primary instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!!!

When you create the `MongoClienteSettings` with `ConnectionString`, the value of `ClusterMode` is automaticly setted to `MULTIPLE`. That doesn't occur with `Builder`...

So, to get the same behavour with `MongoClientSetting.Builder()`, you need to set it. Like this:

```java
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(settings ->
                    settings
                         .hosts(singletonList(new ServerAddress(
                                    getHost(), Integer.parseInt(getPort()))))
                         .requiredReplicaSetName("rs0")
                         .requiredClusterType(ClusterType.REPLICA_SET)
                         .mode(ClusterConnectionMode.MULTIPLE))
            )
            .applyToSslSettings(setting ->
                    setting.enabled(true)
            )
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
            .credential(getCredential())
            .build());
}
```

Now it's working well :)

[AWS CloudWatch Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsKLP.png)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what we needed, thank you!